# Remove_action does not work

Tags: filters, hooks

I am using Shopwise theme. In the category pages, the woocommerce shop loop is being used. The template for each product in the list view is retrieved from content-product.php.

Here's what I added in shopwise/woocommerce/content-product.php:

```
/**
     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
     */
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 ); // doesn't work for some reason.
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

I know that this file is being used as the template, because when I try other modifications (i.e. echo 'this', or commenting out all of the code), I do see an effect. However, when I add the `remove_action` line, nothing happens.

For now, I'm using CSS to hide the price on list view, but I want to know why the other approach is not working.

Comment: Where are you adding this code? It may be beneficial to wrap this in a [`plugins_loaded`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/) hook

Comment: @Howdy_McGee It's in my theme's woocommerce/content-product.php. Do you mean something like this? `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_list_price', 99 );
function remove_list_price() {
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
}` I tried that in my functions.php, but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe move any `add_action()` calls and callbacks into the themes functions.php instead of inside the template.

Comment: @Professional_Helper try looking for `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );` in the template (`content-product.php`) and then move your `remove_action()` to above that `do_action()` instead.

Comment: @SallyCJ that's what I originally did. The code you're seeing in my post is exactly that.

Comment: No, the `do_action()` in your post is for the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` hook, not `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title` - note the "after_".